# Change date to tomorrow's date

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking to extend the date to the next day, If the date is less than todays date.

here's what I have.

```
$today = $date = date('y/d/m h:i:s a', time());

 $query_moline = "SELECT * FROM penny WHERE `active`='Y' ORDER BY `sdate` ASC LIMIT 13";
$moline = mysql_query($query_moline) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row_moline = mysql_fetch_assoc($moline);
$totalRows_moline = mysql_num_rows($moline);
?>
<table width="98%"><tr><td>Title</td><td><?php echo $today ?></td><td>Fee</td></tr>
<? if($totalRows_moline>0)
{ ?> 
<?php do { ?>
 <?php
$id=$row_moline['id'];
$title=$row_moline['title'];
$sdate=$row_moline['sdate'];
$fee=$row_moline['fee'];

if($sdate<$today){
$sdate=$today;

$strsql="UPDATE `penny` SET `sdate`=\"$sdate\" WHERE `id`=\"$id\"";
//echo $strsql."<BR>";
mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

Here's where I'm stuck, if `$sdate<$today` then I need `$sdate` to be tomorrows date but with the same time as `$sdate`

for example if $sdate= 2011/4/12 14:00:00 
then I need the new date to be 2011/5/12 14:00:00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try (if I understand what you need)

```
UPDATE penny SET sdate = DATE_ADD($sdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to adjust it via php, you can convert the mysql datetime field to an int using `strtotime` (though Marco's suggestion will be less work, cleaner code and all kinds of goodness)

```
$row_time = strtotime( $row_moline['sdate'] );
```

and either add the time in seconds

```
$row_time += 86400
```

or use `strtotime` again

```
$row_time_tomorrow = strtotime( '+1 day', $row_time )
```

when saving back to the db, you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to convert in the query, e.g.

```
"UPDATE `whatever` set `date` = FROM_UNIXTIME( $row_time_tomorrow ) WHERE id = 9001"
```